# mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory issue

Tags: magento2

When I try to execute a command, I get below error by commandline

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

[image]

Please assist me as soon possible.

Answer (score 0):

So try with -d memory_limit=4G

Comment: Thank You for your Reply , I solved it by access using root user :)